# Convert source IP address from struct iphdr* to string equivalent using Linux netfilter

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

I want to convert the source & destination IP addresses from a packet captured using netfilter to char *.

In my netfilter hook function, I have:

```
sock_buff = skb; // argument 2 of hook function

// ip_header is struct iphdr*
ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(sock_buff);

// now how to convert ip_header->saddr & ip_header->daddr to char *
// ip_header->saddr & ip_header->daddr are of type __be32
```

Thanks.

Comment: @ott-- The conversion has to be done in the kernel module. I could  not find a header file in linux/ folder containing inet_ntoa() function. I did find in_aton() in linux/inet.h which does exactly the opposite, converts char* to __be32.

Comment: Oops, kernel. Try this; `printk("ip-address is " NIPQUAD_FMT "\n", NIPQUAD(ip_header->saddr));`. I cannot access my linux hosts from here, so I can't tell where the macros are defined. And it's for ipv4 only.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The kernel's family of `printf()` functions has a special format specifier for IP-addresses (`%pI4` for IPv4-addresses, `%pI6` for IPv6).

So with IPv4, you could use something like:

```
char source[16];
snprintf(source, 16, "%pI4", &ip_header->saddr); // Mind the &!
```

Or write to dynamically allocated memory.

If you simply want to print debug-output, you can also use `printk()`. For the many other features of `%p`, see [this document](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt).

Answer (score 1):

Try `in4_pton()` function in `net/core/utils.c` (definition: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/core/utils.c#L118)

```c
#include <linux/inet.h>

char source[16];
in4_pton(source, -1, &ip_header->saddr, '\0', NULL);
```