# Comparison of two IPs

Tags: c, linux, comparison, ip-address, kernel-module

I am required to compare two IPs. One IP is stored in `u8` format where I managed to convert it to `char *` which i stored in the variable `arp_tbuf`. However, the second IP to be compared is in `u32` format (from `ip.h`). But every time I try to convert the IP in `u32` format to `char *` as follows,

```
    unsigned int pkt_da = (unsigned int)ip_header->daddr;   
    char pkt_tbuf[16];
    char pkt_tbuf_tmp[4];

    pkt_tbuf_tmp[0] = pkt_da & 0x000000FF;
    pkt_tbuf_tmp[1] = (pkt_da & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
    pkt_tbuf_tmp[2] = (pkt_da & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
    pkt_tbuf_tmp[3] = (pkt_da & 0xFF000000) >> 24;  
    sprintf(pkt_tbuf, "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", pkt_tbuf_tmp[0], pkt_tbuf_tmp[1], pkt_tbuf_tmp[2], pkt_tbuf_tmp[3]);
```

I get a `kernel panic` error.

I am aware of the functionality `memcmp` to compare to characters.

It would be a great help if you experts would help me in converting this IP to `char *` and **to compare the two IP's** like `memcmp(arp_tbuf, pkt_tbuf)`.

Thank you very much :)

**EDIT**

As @BobJarvis suggested, I ran the code again in my kernel. IT worked fine for converting the IPs in the LAN. However, When I loaded the web page, the `kernel panic` error occured. I there a cleaner way to perform this IP conversion from `unsigned int` into `char *` (dotted IP format) ?

Comment: @BobJarvis ohh mistake..I will correct in the question :)

Comment: Now, what do you mean by "u8 format"? Please show the declaration. Thanks.

Comment: @JimGarrison ohh I will check on that asap..totally missed it. thank you very much :)

Comment: @JimGarrison putting `%s` also did not work. c an you suggest any alternative way to fix this?

Comment: @BobJarvis `u8` is the type defined by the header which i refer to when getting the first IP :)

Comment: Isn't `u8` only an octet while `u32` is the full 4 octets?

Comment: @alvits ohh..is there a way to convert u32 to char * ?

Comment: Can you open up the header and post the definition of `u8`? I can think of several possible ways that something named `u8` might be defined...

Comment: @JimGarrison - it's been a while, but I seem to recall that when arguments of a numeric type smaller than `int` (e.g. `char`) are passed to a variadic function in C/C++ the argument will be expanded to int on the stack. Or is this just my memory playing tricks on me?

Comment: I just tested your code at [Ideone](https://ideone.com/yaCaSw) and it compiled and ran fine. (Note that I used a literal for the IP address). There must be something else in your code that's causing the kernel panic. Try taking the code I tested at Ideone, compile and run it at your site, and see what you get. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis ohh.. thank you sir for trying that out..I must then see to the rest of the code :)

Comment: Why are you putting `n` in your string? And why do you think the kernel panic occurs anywhere in the code you have posted?

Comment: @JimGarrison Bob Jarvis is right: the `char` arguments will be automatically promoted to `int`s.

Comment: @SteveEmmerson thanks - it's been awhile since I wrote a C program :-( I should have double-checked.

Comment: @n.m. thank you for the reply .. :) because all these error occurred after implementing the new code to convert to string. otherwise it worked just fine :)

Comment: "occurred after" does not entail "occured within". 16 characters are not enough to contain 4 3-character quads *and* three dots *and* a newline *and* the terminating null character. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the explanation give by  @DavidC.Rankin I was able to narrow down and look for more solution. Thus, I found a similar post which solved the question of Converting the int IP to dotted IP,
[Convert source IP address from struct iphdr* to string equivalent using Linux netfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296835/convert-source-ip-address-from-struct-iphdr-to-string-equivalent-using-linux-ne)

Then I just performed a `memcmp()`

```
int cmp;
cmp=memcmp ( arp_tbuf, pkt_tbuf, sizeof(arp_tbuf) );

if((cmp > 0) || (cmp < 0)){
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Not matching");              
}
```

Thank you experts for the assistance in helping me understand the issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are running into problems with values (any 2 byte part of the IP) exceeding 127. The `>>` operator is an **arithmetic shift** (sign preserving) shift and not a **logical shift**. (see  [**Shift operator in C**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622/shift-operator-in-c) ). You can see this in your code with simple tests of `pkt_da = 0x7f7f7f7f` and `pkt_da = 0x80808080`. Printing the values with:

```
for (it = 0; it < 4; it++)
    printf ("  pkt_tbuf_tmp[%2d]: %u\n", it, pkt_tbuf_tmp[it]);
```

Gives:

```
./bin/pktb 2139062143
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 0]: 127
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 1]: 127
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 2]: 127
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 3]: 127
Done - pkt_tbuf='127.127.127.127'

./bin/pktb 2155905152
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 0]: 4294967168
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 1]: 4294967168
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 2]: 4294967168
pkt_tbuf_tmp[ 3]: 4294967168
Done - pkt_tbuf='-128.-128.-128.-128'
```

The right-shift behavior is compiler dependent. So what works on one box, may not on another system.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply..i will check post back :)

Comment: Yes you absolutely right..what would be your solution to fix this sir? so that it could support all ip values?

Comment: I am glad you found a solution. It was along what I was thinking. Take a look at the `inet_pton` function as well.

Comment: Yes sir, you suggestion helped me look for specific solutions for my problem.. thank you very much +1