# Linux C - Convert `iphdr->daddr` to equivalent string - doesn't work anymore?

Tags: c, linux, header, ip

There are several threads about how to convert the ip-adresses in `struct iphdr` to strings (like `127.0.0.1`) with the same method, for example:

[Convert source IP address from struct iphdr* to string equivalent using Linux netfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296835/convert-source-ip-address-from-struct-iphdr-to-string-equivalent-using-linux-ne)

But somehow they aren't working for me:

```
char daddr_str[16];

struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(buf);

snprintf(daddr_str, sizeof(daddr_str), "%pI4", &iph->daddr);
printf("IP: %s\n", daddr_str);
```

And I get:

```
IP: 0x7f5870621020I
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now did it the other way around:

```
struct sockaddr_in ip;

inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &ip.sin_addr);

if(ip.sin_addr.s_addr == iph->daddr) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be that your are not properly extracting the IP-Header from the packet. At the beginning of the buffer usually lies the Ethernet header first and the IP header follows afterwards - so in order to get the IP-Header you need to:

```
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr*)(buf + sizeof(struct ethhdr));
```

Hope it helped in your case, here is also a [nice guide](https://opensourceforu.com/2015/03/a-guide-to-using-raw-sockets/)

**Edit**

You are right, this was not the actual problem in your case. I tried it out by myself and also get just the address.

After some research I think that the real cause is that these special format strings like `%pI4` are only known by the kernel implementation of these functions and not by the stdlib implementation.
So this attempt will only work when developing a kernel module e.g.

Comment: I don't think this is correct because all my other checks (sequence number and next-header type) match up. I am using a `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);`.